# Parametros enviados depois de função acabar

Tags: javascript, funções

Provavelmente é uma pergunta de novato, mas gostaria de perceber para que serve, com exemplo melhor ainda, para que servem parametros enviados depois de uma função ser executada.
Por exemplo, neste pedaço de código:

```
...
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
   return function() {
   contentIcon = '<div id="iconContent"><p>' +locations[i][0]+ '<br>' +locations[i][1]+ '<br>' +locations[i][2]+ '</p></div>';
      infowindow.setContent(contentIcon);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
   }
})(marker, i));
```

Para que serve o `...(marker, i));` no final? Quando se deve usar?

Outro exemplo:

```
   ...
   function randomChar() {
      ...
      return arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)];
   }

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Miguel, creio que esta pergunta é sobre o mesmo que a outra pergunta. Marquei como duplicada. Diz se achares que não ficou claro na mesma.

Comment: Obrigado Sergio, sim fiquei esclarecido. O que faço agora com esta pergunta?

Comment: Ótimo! Podes deixar a pergunta. Pode ser que haja outros que procurem por palavras ou titulo que usaste e assim têm mais chances de encontrar a informação que precisam.